# Xe7 Simple Soap with THTTPRIO gives error Unable to load WSDL File/Location

Tags: delphi, soap

I am trying to make a simple Soap call with THTTPRIO on XE7

it works as expected in my win10 developement machine.
it works another Win7 machine as expected.
But not another win7 machine.

It returns

Unable to load WSDL File/Location ... SoapAction:''

When i try to import wsdl file with Wsdlimp.exe it gives the same error.

When i use soapui tool it performs same actions without problem.

There is no firewall or antivirus program.

Both Win7 machines are connected via the same modem to the internet.

Does can somebody suggest me something ?

Best regards..